# Ошибка disnake.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: NameError: name 'Menu' is not defined

Tags: python, discord, disnake

Решил значит сделать в боте меню через кнопки и решил для теста хотя бы просто кнопку добавить, так как с когами работаю впервые. Перерыл интернет и не нашёл ничего подобного

```
import disnake
from disnake.ext import commands
from typing import Optional


class commands(commands.Cog):

    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        print(print(f"Bot {self.bot.user} is ready to work!"))

    class Menu(disnake.ui.View):
        def __init__(self):
            super().__init__(timeout=None)
            self.value: Optional[bool] = None

        @disnake.ui.button(label='1', style=disnake.ButtonStyle.gray)
        async def get_menu(self, button: disnake.Button, interaction: disnake.Interaction):
            await interaction.response.send_message("Ты нажал 1")

    @commands.command(name="menu")
    async def menu(self, ctx):
        view = Menu()

        await ctx.send("Меню", view=view)
        await view.wait()

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(commands(bot))
```

в Pycharm красным подсвечивается строка `view = Menu()` но я никак не могу понять в чём дело

Пробовал тот же код запускать даже через основной файл бота, но у вы так тоже не работает

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется ты кнопки совсем не так добавляешь...

Основываясь на документацию disnake, кнопки добавляются через [disnake.Button](https://docs.disnake.dev/en/stable/api/components.html#disnake.Button). Такого `view = Main()` **вообще не существует** *!!* в документации.

Вот пример слеш-команды, в которой отправляется кнопочка.

```py
@bot.slash_command()
async def button(inter):
    await inter.response.send_message("ураа кнопочка",
    components=[
        disnake.ui.Button(label="Название", style=disnake.ButtonStyle.blurple, custom_id="id")]
    )
```

Также вы можете прочитать документации [стилям](https://docs.disnake.dev/en/stable/api/components.html#disnake.ButtonStyle), а также поизучать как [взаимодействовать с ними](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76594405/discord-bot-on-disnake-how-do-i-make-the-button-inactive-after-clicking) *(Вопрос с англ. stackoverflow)*.

Простите за очень поздний ответ, просто не мог увидить вопрос раньше. Надеюсь помог!

Comment: В общем тут прикольчик был совсем не в том как я кнопочки делал, они сами по себе то работали, а вот в когах нет. Проблему я уже решил. Но за твой ответ тоже спасибо!